# Asp.Net error reporting with stacktrace

Tags: asp.net, error-handling

I have an Asp.Net web site set up to log errors using Log4Net (in global.asax) and redirect users to a custom error page (set up in web.config with: ). On this error page the users have the opportunity to write about what they did when the error occurred and post the description back to us to help fix the problem.

My question is this: How do i connect the error stacktrace to the users error report?

It appears that .Net has handled the error when it was written to the log file and the custom error page has no information about the stacktrace. If only I could see the stacktrace from the custom error page code-behind my problem would be solved.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to generate an ID when you log the error, and pass that ID to the custom error page, where it can be stored with the user's report.